# Extract the sub string matching regex

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to extract `22 chocolates` from the following string:

```
   SOMETEXT for 2 FFXX. Another 22 chocolates & 45 chamkila.
```

using regex `\\d+\\s*(chocolates.|chocolate.)`. I used :

```
grep("\\d+\\s*(chocolates.|chocolate.)",s)
```

but it does not give the string `22 chocolates`. How could I extract the part that is matching the regex?

Comment: "[0-9]+ chocolates" works for me in sublime

Comment: @iOSDeveloper It just returns a number, which is equal to 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an option using `sub` from base R:

```
x <- "SOMETEXT for 2 FFXX. Another 22 chocolates & 45 chamkila."
sub(".*?(\\d+ chocolates?).*", "\\1", x)

22 chocolates
```

The pattern in parentheses, `(\\d+ chocolates?)`, is a *capture* group, and is available as `\\1` after `sub` has run on the match.

### Demo

**Edit:**

As you have seen, if `sub` cannot find an exact match, it will return the input string.  This behavior often makes sense, because in a case where a substitution does not make sense, you would want the input to not be changed.

If you need to find out whether or not the pattern matches, then calling `grep` is one option:

```
grep(".*(\\d+ chocolates?).*",x,value = FALSE)
```

Comment: Could you explain why doesn't `sub("\\d+\\s*(wins.|win.)","\\1",c("Nominated for 2 Oscars. Another 22 wins & 64 nominations."))` work? Also what does `\\1` mean?

Comment: Okay, and how to check if the match ever occurred? For example, if I change `chocolates` to `chocos`, it just returns the entire string

Comment: `sub` is substituting one string (matched by regex pattern) for another. If the pattern can't match, then there's nothing to be substituted, so the original string will return.

Comment: If you look carefully in your "wins" example, a substitution does occur. The entire matched pattern "22 wins" is replaced with the part of the pattern within the capture group "wins", ie: the "22 " is removed.

Comment: @rosscova Had a small query. What is the use of `?` in `.*?` in the complete regex `.*?(\\d+ chocolates?).*`. Why can't it just be `.*`?

Comment: @SuhailGupta The `?` in `.*?` makes the dot all _lazy_.  Check the capture using just `.*` and you will see that only the _last_ digit is there.   This is because the dot consumed the other digits.  Making the dot lazy fixes this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your original pattern does not return `22 chocolates` because it is a pattern that should be used in a *matching* function, while `grep` only returns whole items in a character vector that contain the match anywhere inside.

Also, note that `(chocolates.|chocolate.)` alternation group can be shortened to `chocolates?.` since the only difference is the plural case for `chocolate` and it can easily be achieved with a `?` quantifier (=1 or 0 occurrences).

A matching function example can be with `stringr::str_extract` (`str_extract_all` to match all occurrences):

```
> library(stringr)
> x <- " SOMETEXT for 2 FFXX. Another 22 chocolates & 45 chamkila."
> p <- "\\d+\\s*chocolates?"
> str_extract(x, p)
[1] "22 chocolates"
```

Or a base R `regmatches`/`regexpr` (or `gregexpr` to extract multiple occurrences) approach:

```
> library(stringr)
> x <- " SOMETEXT for 2 FFXX. Another 22 chocolates & 45 chamkila."
> p <- "\\d+\\s*chocolates?"
> regmatches(x, regexpr(p, x))
[1] "22 chocolates"
```